# running substrate benchmaks errors at setjmp file not found

Tags: substrate, polkadot

Working on substare node-template , When I run benchmark I get the below error. It says 'setjmp.h' file not found. I am working on Macbook pro

```
$cargo build --release --features runtime-benchmarks
```

error: failed to run custom build command for `wasmtime-runtime v1.0.2`

```
  Caused by:
    process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/yusufkelo/Documents/Developer/workspaces/substrate-projects/substrate-node-template-2023/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/release/build/wasmtime-runtime-04bf801e868dc470/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
    --- stdout
    cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/helpers.c
    TARGET = Some("wasm32-unknown-unknown")
    OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
    HOST = Some("aarch64-apple-darwin")
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_wasm32-unknown-unknown
    CC_wasm32-unknown-unknown = None
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_wasm32_unknown_unknown
    CC_wasm32_unknown_unknown = None
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_CC
    TARGET_CC = None
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
    CC = None
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_wasm32-unknown-unknown
    CFLAGS_wasm32-unknown-unknown = None
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_wasm32_unknown_unknown
    CFLAGS_wasm32_unknown_unknown = None
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_CFLAGS
    TARGET_CFLAGS = None
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
    CFLAGS = None
    cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
    CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
    DEBUG = Some("false")
    running: "clang" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-DCFG_TARGET_OS_unknown" "-DCFG_TARGET_ARCH_wasm32" "-o" "/Users/yusufkelo/Documents/Developer/workspaces/substrate-projects/substrate-node-template-2023/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/build/wasmtime-runtime-b8e432731307a73b/out/src/helpers.o" "-c" "src/helpers.c"
    cargo:warning=src/helpers.c:1:10: fatal error: 'setjmp.h' file not found
    cargo:warning=#include <setjmp.h>
    cargo:warning=         ^~~~~~~~~~
    cargo:warning=1 error generated.
    exit status: 1

    --- stderr
```